# Join multiple “dynamic”rows into one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a range of cells in columns A to be combined into one Cell in column B the range of these cell is dynamic. How can I combine these cells? see [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEuAx.jpg) for more explanation.

My scenario is similar scenario to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1269109/combine-multiple-dynamicrows-into-one-cell/1269127) but with little different,  the difference is the empty row which  needed to be combined-in is above rows as shown in in the image [The-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaMJW.jpg)

I tried to make changes to the formula which was in the post  but i could not succeed.

The formula is 
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),TEXTJOIN1(",",FALSE,OFFSET(B2,-(ROW()-MAX(IF(ISBLANK($B$1:B1),ROW($B$1:B1),0))-1),0):OFFSET(B2,-1,0)),"")

need help to fix the formula to suit my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your solution. In this example the sample data is in Cells B2:B17. For this solution to work, you should leave one blank cell before the data and after the data i.e. B1 & B18 in this case. It's assumed that there's only one blank cell between the ranges, else the solution may not work correctly.

If your version of Excel does not have TEXTJOIN function, use below UDF in VBA to create one. Press ALT + F11 to access VBA Editor. Insert a Module from Insert Menu. Double click on the Module name in left pane to access its code editor.

Paste the following code into it.

```
Function TEXTJOIN1(delimiter As String, ignore_empty As Boolean, ParamArray cell_ar() As Variant)
    For Each cellrng In cell_ar
        For Each cell In cellrng
            If ignore_empty = False Then
                result = result & cell & delimiter
            Else
                If cell <> "" Then
                    result = result & cell & delimiter
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    Next cellrng
    TEXTJOIN1 = Left(result, Len(result) - Len(delimiter))
End Function
```

Save the file as Macro Enabled WOrkbook XLSM if you have Excel 2007 and above.

In Cell C1 put the following formula and drag it down up to length of your column data. As mentioned above very first cell and very last cell should be blank.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1),TEXTJOIN1(",",FALSE,OFFSET(B1,1,0):OFFSET(B1,MIN(IF(ISBLANK(B2:$B$18),ROW(B2:$B$18)-ROW(B2),9^99)),0)),"")
```

Press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. The formula shall be enclosed in Curly Braces to indicate that it's an array formula.

Now drag it down along the length of the column.

[image]